# Generate a package like rocket.chat.cordova

Tags: meteor, less

I made ​​some changes to rocket.chat, adding a few pages and css styles , and I have a question: how can I generate a package like rocket.chat.cordova.

Due to the css styles built in server, when I run 'meteor run ios', it can't load styles and shows me the blank screen.